# Experiencing random freezes on React Native Android Screen that uses WebSockets and gets updated frequently

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket, memory-leaks

## What's on the screen

I am building an app that allows the users to place live bids on items through WebSockets and the highest bidder gets the item.

The screen is simple, it has cards of items that displays the item information like images and information like price etc, and it changes after every items gets sold to certain user.

A bid window where the current highest bid and bidder gets displayed and the timer is going on to show the seconds left before this item gets sold.

A list of users with the items they have bought so far and the next items in queue.

A toggle that allows users to place bids automatically

Few Buttons from where the user can place bids on the items.

Note: All these are separate components, but the state updates has to be done on the parent component only to share the updates across all the child components, since the requirement is such.

## Problem

Note: Problem only occurs in build APK made from .\gradlew assembleRelease not in Development Build.

When the users are placing bids on items very frequently, its like 2 to 3 bids per second, after 15 to 18 items the entire screen gets frozen, no state updates, no UI changes, just stuck, only the toggle, side menu (which I drag from left) and the scrolling related things work on the screen. Ultimately the user has to close the app (using Home Button) remove the app from recent and re-run the application.

This is happening very randomly, on some devices it happens very quickly (4 to 5 items) but in some devices like it takes 17 to 18 items to freeze.

## Patterns

There are some patterns to this problem which we have experienced.

- When the users bid very aggressively the app freezes more quicker.
- When there are more number of users bidding, it freezes.
- The devices we have used ranged from 2GB RAM to 8GB RAM, but the strange thing to notice is that in 2GB device the app didn't freeze that quickly and sometimes didn't freeze at all, however in 6GB and 8GB phones it froze more quicker.

## Logic

The logic is simple, when the user gets into the auction, the network request goes out asking the connection from the socket server that is actually conducting the auction, when the connection is established, the client is provided with the snapshot of the auction that contains the current information of the auction like the amount, current Bidder etc. The client side code then updates it's UI states accordingly. Now the user is connected with the socket and getting live updates about the auction through different events and all this happens within a `useEffect` without any dependency.

When the user bids, the bid event is sent to the server, the server then broadcast that message to other connected users saying "that this user just placed a bid of this amount on this item" and all users update their states accordingly including the bidder.

```
{
  "name": "--",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.47.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^5.1.3",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.2",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-sse": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.14.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.7",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "github:tradle/rn-nodeify",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

This is the list of things we have tried to solve this issue, none is successful.

## Check for Memory Leaks

I ran profiling on Android Studio of Development Build to check for the memory leak and see if the memory is going really up. I saw that the memory never went above 300mb and the entire auction of 30 items ended. It was just for checking for any memory leaks, I always knew the app will never freeze on Development it only freezes on release APK.

I did profiling on both Emulator and the physical device.

## Enabled Hermes Engine

It didn't work too

## Tried newArchEnabled

Tried enabling new architecture and made all CMakeList changes, but then the app didn't open at all, my Android12 showed the "This app contains bugs" message on release build and the development build kept crashing.

## Enhanced code with removeEventListeners and other fixes related to state updates

I minimized the state updates and removed any unnecessary setStates, brought the related variables inside useRefs, removed eventListeners in the clean up functions.

## CPU Threads in Profiling

I checked the CPU main thread and UI Thread for any unnecessary activity and found out that it only works when it is required to, like it show the activity only on events where the state is actually updated.